# Java generics from Cay Horstmann, Core Java 7, Volume I, page 716

Tags: java, generics

I am learning Java 7 generics, reading Cay Horstmann, Core Java7, Volume I, on page 716.
I dont understand why the run time error (cast illegal) occurs, please see code below.
Can anyone explain it to me better than Cay does?

```
public class ProcessArgs 
{

  public static <T extends Comparable> T[] minmax(T... a)
  {
    Object[] mm = new Object[2];
    mm[0] = a[0];
    mm[1] = a[1];
    if (mm[0] instanceof Comparable)
    {
        System.out.println("Comparable"); // this is True, prints Comparable at run-time
    }
    return (T[]) mm;  // run-time error here

    /* Run-Time ERROR as below:
     ComparableException in thread "main" 
     java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Comparable;
      at ProcessArgs.minmax(ProcessArgs.java:13)
      at ProcessArgs.main(ProcessArgs.java:18)
     */

  }

  public static void main(String[] args) 
  {
    String[] sa = minmax("Hello","World"); // ERROR, illegal cast
    System.out.println(sa[0] + sa[1]);
    Object o = "Hello World"; //works - if we comment out the method call to minmax above
    Comparable<String> s = (Comparable) o; // works
    Comparable s2 = (Comparable) o; // works
    System.out.println(s + " " + (String) s2); // works
    return;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

It throws an error because the actual type you created, `Object[]` is NOT a `Comparable`.  Java generics deal pretty poorly with arrays, you should try to use Collections if possible.  For this case, you can create an array of the proper type using reflection:

```
T[] mm = (T[]) Array.newInstance(a[0].getClass(), 2 );
```

Given these two lines:

```
Object o = "Hello World"; //works - if we comment out the method call to minmax above
Comparable<String> s = (Comparable) o; // works
```

The second line works because the string `"Hello World"` actually is a `Comparable`.

But `Object[]` isn't, its type is `Object[]`, so it can't be cast.

Comment: But the statement: if (mm[0] instanceof Comparable) returns true, in my code, the generic type erasure of T... a is Comparable.

Comment: further: if I change it from Object[] to this: Comparable[] mm = new Comparable[2]; instead of Object[] - I still get error at run time [Ljava.lang.Comparable; cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.String;

Comment: mm[0] is one element in the array.  It's not the array itself, which is what you are trying to cast later in the code.

Comment: Even if you change `Object array` to `Comparable array`, the return value will create problem while doing casting to `T[]`

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that.  Generics and arrays don't really mix.  I added a correct example using reflection.

Answer (score 1):

Just to give you hint, you can compare below code and understand what is happening in that code.

```
Object[] mm = new Object[2]; // reference type Object array and object type object array.
mm[0] = a[0]; // putting String value into 0th position, so it is comparable,
// but whole array is of type Object, so it is not able to cast it to String array while returning.

Object o = "Hello World"; // reference type Object and object type String
Object o = new String("Hello World"); // this code is also similar to above line.
```

**Note:** String is comparable, but not the Object array.