# ClassCastException when extending a generic class

Tags: java, arrays, generics, libgdx

Let's say I have a class `Text` which implement an interface called `Drawable` which is defined as follow :

```
public interface Drawable {

  public void draw (DrawConfig drawConfig);
}
```

I want to have an object which acts like an array with items but which implements `Drawable` as well, to be able to write `drawables.draw(drawConfig)` and having it forward the call to all its children instead of having to do a for loop. So I first created a wrapper class which looks like this :

```
public class Drawables implements Drawable {

  private final Array<Drawable> items = new Array<Drawable>();

  public void add (final Drawable value) {
    this.items.add(value);
  }

  @Override
  public void draw (final DrawConfig drawConfig) {
    for (final T item : this.items)
      item.draw(drawConfig);
  }
}
```

**The first problem** is that as it's a wrapper it doesn't have any of the `Array` class methods and I have to manually add the ones I need (like `add()` in the example above).

**The second problem** is that if I store only `Text` objects in it, I can't write :

```
for (Text t : drawables)
    t.setText("blablabla");
```

Which means I have to make **another** array and I'll end up with two arrays just for that. I want to avoid that so I thought about using genericity as the `Array` class is generic and I turned my `Drawables` class into this :

```
public class Drawables<T extends Drawable> extends Array<T> implements Drawable {

  @Override
  public void draw (final DrawConfig drawConfig) {
    for (final T item : this.items) // Line 17
      item.draw(drawConfig);
  }
}
```

And now I can write :

```
Drawables<Text> drawables = new Drawables<Text>();

drawables.add(new Text());
drawables.add(new Text());

for (Text t : drawables)
    t.setText("blablabla");

drawables.draw(drawConfig);
```

And it compiles !! **Except that** at runtime I get the following error :

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [La.b.c.ui.Drawable;
    at a.b.c.Drawables.draw(Drawables.java:17)
    at a.b.c.ui.components.Text_UseTest.render(Text_UseTest.java:80)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:215)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:120)
```

See the comment in my code for line 17.

What is the problem? And is it even possible to achieve what I want to do?

Comment: What is `Array<T>`?  It's not the built-in `Array` class.

Comment: @markspace http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/utils/Array.html

Comment: @LucasRoss, but it can behave like one. That is all an interface states

Comment: I'm not 100% sure how your custom `Array<T>` class works, but there's some information in this StackOverflow question about dealing with arrays and generics: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30388464/java-generics-from-cay-horstmann-core-java-7-volume-i-page-716/30388651#30388651

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class Array implements Iterable. So you can write like this.

```
@Override
public void draw (final DrawConfig drawConfig) {
  for (final T item : this) // Line 17
      item.draw(drawConfig);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you have your design right. Instead of separating drawing a single item and drawing multiple items, `Drawable` should only specify in its contract that it draws according to some config. How it does this, or what other objects it uses to do this, is not important.

Hence, I would first do this:

```
public interface Drawable {
    void draw (DrawConfig drawConfig);    
}
```

Now it appears that you want your `Drawable` to maintain a private member. This private member has some bearing on how things are drawn. The interesting bit is that it could be the thing itself being drawn, or perhaps it could contain things that need to be drawn, or maybe it's something else entirely. We don't know at this point *how* it would impact the behavior of `draw`. So how do we handle that? Well we can create an abstract class that maintains this private member and also implements `Drawable`:

```
public abstract class AbstractDrawable<T> implements Drawable {    
    protected T data;           
}
```

Notice that there is no implementation for `draw`. This is on purpose because it's only in the concrete implementation that we will actually define a behavior for `draw`. You can easily see now how we have split two concerns (maintaining state and implementing behavior). Now we can define a concrete implementation which define *how* it will maintain state and *how* it will implement behavior:

```
public class Drawables<T extends Drawable> extends AbstractDrawable<List<T>> {

    public Drawables() {
        this.data = new ArrayList<T>();
    }

    public void addDrawable(T item) {
        this.data.add(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void draw (final DrawConfig drawConfig) {
        for (final T item : this.data) {
            item.draw(drawConfig);
        }
    }
}
```

Here we have a very specific implementation of `AbstractDrawable<T>` that itself works with a list of drawables. This concrete implementation has defined how it manages state (it uses an internal list of `Drawable` instances) and how it manages behavior as well (its "draw" behavior is to "draw" each `Drawable` instance that it maintains).

You mentioned that you want all the list methods, etc. It's not a good idea to extend a class simply to get access to its method. Your list of drawable items is not really a list. It is a drawable that happens to work with a list of drawables. The approach above implicitly uses composition over inheritance, because `AbstractDrawable<T>` encapsulates some internal data that will be drawn in some manner (not important *how* this is done; just that it is done). So instead of extending `List<T>`, you can now maintain an internal list that you can then "draw" in a manner you choose. This is exactly what happens in the concrete implementation `Drawables<T extends Drawable>`.

Your next question is about not being able to call `t.setText()` on `Text` instances. The only way you can do this is if you have a concrete instance that works specifically on `Text` instances, or if you performed `instanceof` checks inside `draw`. This is because all you have is `T extends Drawable`; the class knows is that it is some kind of `Drawable`, and that it is able to `draw`. Other than that, it has no idea about the specific implementations.

Comment: For this to work `AbstractDrawable` has to be declared *abstract* and `data` has to be declared *protected*. Also, I tried your code and I can't instanciate the `Drawables` class cause whetever I pass to it for the type T I have an error.

Comment: @Flawyte Edited the typos. You'll never instantiate a `Drawable` directly. I'm assuming you have stuff like `Text` which implements `Drawable`. So what you're going to be creating is an instance of `Drawables<Text>`. You could create an instance of `Drawables<Drawable>` as well, and give it anything that implements `Drawable`.

Comment: Yeah with your post edited now I can do `Drawables<Text> drawables = new Drawables<Text>()` but I have two problems : 1)  I still have to manually add `add()`, `remove()` methods etc. to `AbstractDrawable` and 2) I can't loop over my `drawables` object anymore cause it's not `Iterable`.

Comment: I don't think those are problems. You have to think about *how* you're using your `Drawables` object. Do you care more about the things inside it being drawn, or do you care about having access to those things themselves? It's not too much work to include `add` and `remove`, and then delegating to the internal list. If you really want access to the list of drawables, you could add a method that returns the internal instance. But I don't see why you couldn't maintain an external list and then just supply elements to `Drawables`. Try not to assign too many responsibilities to one class (SRP).

Answer (score 0):

The problem after erasure:

```
for (final Drawable item : this.items) // this.items is of Object[]!!!
```

Now the for loop doesn't know how to cast (no implicit casts in java). You couldn't simple write `Drawable item = new Object();`. You have to do the cast yourself:

```
for (Object o : this.items) {
  Drawable item = (Drawable) o;
  item.draw(drawConfig);
}
```

Related: [Cast element in Java For Each statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2480316/cast-element-in-java-for-each-statement)

Comment: Wouldn't casting each item be very expensive? And as I'm extending `Array<T>` I don't understand why it's considered as an array of `Object` and not as an array of `Text` when I instanciate it.

Comment: @Flawyte, check [this question](/q/313584/) if you want to understand erasure and why it is needed.